# Angularjs Scope Issue with Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive, form where the rest of the html is given. The directive is given below

THis is the html for directive

```
  <div test
  input="{{guage.input}}"
  >
  </div>

angular.module('test', [])

        .directive('test', function () {
            "use strict";

            return {

                restrict: 'A',

                scope: {
                    input: '='
                },

                templateUrl: 'gauge/gauge.tpl.html',

                replace: true
    });
```

The below is the html loaded after the directive compilation.

```
<div ng-controller="Testing">
<div>
    <div id="{{guageid}}" class="gauge ng-isolate-scope" ng-model="gauge.input" data-service="/api/getDataResult/core-mon-status" guageid="fleet_online" description="Fraction of fleet online" unit="%" test="{{gauge.test}}" input="{{gauge.input}}" gauge="">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now I have a parent controller above this dom element name is Testing.

From my controller if I change the {{guage.input}} its not displaying.

This is my controller

```
app.controller('Testing',['$scope','newdataLoad','$timeout',function($scope, newdataLoad, $timeout){
        $scope.gauge = {};
$scope.gauge.input = 0;
});
```

What is the problem with my scope here.

Comment: excuse my question but what does '=?' in the scope definition means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your scope defines the `input` with `=` you dont need the expression brackets.

```
<div test input="guage.input">
```

Using expression brackets will break the 2-way binding.

---

Optimization:

You can completely move you controller into the directive and still make use of the dependency injection

```
 "use strict"; 
    angular.module('test', []).directive('test', function () {   
       return {    
            restrict: 'A',    
            scope: {
              input: '='
            },    
            templateUrl: 'gauge/gauge.tpl.html',    
            replace: true,
            controller: function($scope, newdataLoad, $timeout){
               $scope.gauge = {};
               $scope.gauge.input = 0;
            }
       }
    });
```

The template code then :

```
<div>
    <div id="{{guageid}}" class="gauge ng-isolate-scope" ng-model="gauge.input" data-service="/api/getDataResult/core-mon-status" guageid="fleet_online" description="Fraction of fleet online" unit="%" test="{{gauge.test}}" input="{{gauge.input}}" gauge="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This may not be the *only* problem, but it certainly is one.

Comment: Hello, I got it working by making the changes. But This directive is there on multiple elements. And $watch triggers even if we change specific element.

Comment: $watch on what, which specific element?

Comment: I have multiple divs with same directive, so when specific change occurs in one place all the other elements are also updated. Say I change the guage value of 1 all other places also the guage value changes.

Comment: sure, because all directives are bound to variable gauge.input. if you have multiple different gauges, you need an other data structure or something

Comment: I got it working..just work around and it works like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove curlies:

```
<div test input="guage.input">
</div>
```